# XSD simpleContent

Tags: xml, xsd

Hello guys i'm having some difficulties with my xsd. Here's the XML codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Modules xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="module.xsd">

<Module code="CSE2041">
<Name shortName="Web 2">Web Technologies II</Name>
<Level>2</Level>
<ResourcePerson>
<FullName>John Smith</FullName>
</ResourcePerson>
</Module>

<Module code="CSE1244">
<Name shortName="ABCD">Some Module Name</Name>
<Level>1</Level>
<ResourcePerson>
<Name>Janet</Name>
<Surname>Higgins</Surname>
</ResourcePerson>
</Module>
</Modules>
```

So basically i'm having problem for the `<Module code="CSE2041">` part. Here's my XSD codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" 

xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:complexType name="moduleType">
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="nameType">
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute name="shortname" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:element name="Modules">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>

<xs:element name="Module" type="moduleType"/>

<xs:element name="Name" type="nameType"/>

<xs:element name="Level" type="xs:integer"/>

<xs:element name="ResourcePerson" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice>

<xs:element name="FullName" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Surname" type="xs:string"/>

</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I'm having problems to close the `<xs:element name="Module" type="moduleType"/>` tag. It must be wrong because i'm getting errors for this part. Can someone tell me how to close it properly? It there any problem in my XSD document? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps you if you properly indent your code.

## xsd

Here

```
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
    <xs:attribute name="shortname" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:extension>
```

You're not properly closing the `extension`. Should be

```
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
    <xs:attribute name="shortname" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:extension>  <!-- Closed -->
```

At the bottom, you have a bunch of useless closing tags (who knows maybe you're not showing us everything

Get rid of those three above the last closing `schema`

Full valid schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"

    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="moduleType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="nameType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="shortname" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Modules">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Module" type="moduleType" />
                <xs:element name="Name" type="nameType" />
                <xs:element name="Level" type="xs:integer" />
                <xs:element name="ResourcePerson" minOccurs="1"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice>
                            <xs:element name="FullName" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Surname" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

## xml

Trying to validate the xml file as is, the fist error you'll see

> Element 'Module' must have no element [children].

You have child elements in the `<Module>` element. `ModuleType` should be nothing more than an empty element with an attribute `code`

After we fix that an try to validate again, we get

> Attribute 'shortName' is not allowed to appear in element 'Name'

`<xs:attribute name="shortname" type="xs:string" />` is case sensitive. `shortName != shortname`

Fix that, then we get

> Invalid content was found starting with element `Module`. One of '{`ResourcePerson`}' is expected.

Why do we get this? Well, your `Modules` element only allows a certain sequence.

1. `<xs:element name="Module">`
2. `<xs:element name="Name">`
3. `<xs:element name="Level">`
4. `<xs:element name="ResourcePerson" maxOccurs="unbounded">`

So you can have just the first three, then as many `ResourcePerson` elements following. So this is what a valid instance document would look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Modules>
    <Module code="CSE2041" />
    <Name shortname="Web 2">Web Technologies II</Name>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <ResourcePerson>
        <FullName>John Smith</FullName>
    </ResourcePerson>
    <ResourcePerson>
        <Surname>Higgins</Surname>
    </ResourcePerson>
</Modules>
```

Notice how `ResourcePerson` only has *one* child element. That's the result of `choice`.

Now I don't think this is the result you are expecting from your schema, so you're probably going to have to take another stab at it.

But maybe you want something more like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="moduleType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="nameType" />
            <xs:element name="Level" type="xs:integer" />
            <xs:element name="ResourcePerson" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:choice>
                        <xs:element name="FullName" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="Surname" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:choice>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="nameType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="shortname" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Modules">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Module" type="moduleType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Where you have a `Module` elements that has that includes the name, level and resource person element. Then in the document level `Modules`, you have an unbounded number of occurrences of `Module`

So this would validate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Modules>
    <Module code="CSE2041">
    <Name shortname="Web 2">Web Technologies II</Name>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <ResourcePerson>
        <FullName>John Smith</FullName>
    </ResourcePerson>
    </Module>
    <Module code="CSE2041">
    <Name shortname="Web 2">Web Technologies II</Name>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <ResourcePerson>
        <FullName>John Smith</FullName>
    </ResourcePerson>
    </Module>
</Modules>
```

As for naming problem. You can probably just a `group` like

```
<xs:group name="NameGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="SurName" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

Then do

```
<xs:element name="ResourcePerson" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="FullName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:group ref="NameGroup"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This way, it's either the `FullName` *or* the `group` of `Name` and `SurName`. Then you could use either for the `ResourcePerson`

```
<ResourcePerson>
    <FullName>John Smith</FullName>
</ResourcePerson>
 -- or --
<ResourcePerson>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <SurName>Smith</SurName>
</ResourcePerson>
```